# Не могу вывести из функции, другую функцию

Tags: javascript

В функции `organizer()` есть событие клик (она увеличивает месяц на один), хочу написать для нее отдельную функцию.

Проблема в том, что как только вывожу из функции она увеличивает только на одни дальше не увеличивает. Функция клик которую я написал находится под функцией `organizer()`.

```js
function organizer() {
  
  var date = new Date();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = date.getMonth();

  forward.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var dateElem = new Date(year, month += 1);
    if (dateElem.getMonth == 11) {
      dateElem.getFullYear += 1;
    };
    alert(dateElem);
  });


};

function forwardClick(monthElem, yearElem) {

  var newDate = new Date(yearElem, monthElem += 1);
  if (newDate.getMonth() == 11) {
    newDate.getFullYear() += 1;
  };

  alert(newDate);
};
```

```html
<button id="forward">&#9658;</button>
```

Comment: mvp предоставьте, хотя бы

Comment: @InDevX я не знаю что такое mvp

Comment: mpv = minimum viable product (минимальный жизнеспособный продукт)

Comment: @InDevX я удалил все что не нужно для понимания

Comment: для понимания тут не хватает воспроизводимого примера - вот что я имел ввиду, а не "лишний" код

Comment: @InDevX  добавил

Comment: @КамранРаджабов что делает ваша функция **forwardClick** и зачем она вам?  Второй вопрос, что вы понимаете под "хочу написать для нее отдельную функцию"?

Comment: @Arsen она должна сделать что и первая только брать переменные из первой

Comment: Вашим алгоритмом вы всегда будете получать одну и ту же дату т.к при каждом клике вы берёте дату "сейчас"... Можете при клике хранить дату в cookie/localStorage или просто в hidden input и при нажатии, брать старую дату и делать +1

Comment: @Arsen я понял что беру одну туже дату, как брать каждый раз измененную новую дату, вот в чем моя проблема ))

Comment: Код излишне избыточный: не нужны ни функции, ни проверка на 11й месяц. Достаточно объекта даты и eventListener'a с инкрементом месяца в одну строку. Более того - значение инкремента можно поместить в data-атрибут, и тогда один листенер можно навесить на все кнопки меняющие месяц. Короче, написано много кода ради кода, и неясно зачем.

Comment: Рекомендую ознакомиться с принципом KISS (Keep It Stupid Simple), и попробовать решать задачи прямо в консоли браузера.

Comment: @yar85 я хочу понять можно сделать так или нет, а вы я так понял лишь бы программа работала и все, как работает не имеет значение, самое главное работает

Comment: @КамранРаджабов, нет - я повторюсь, именно твое решение в вопросе демонстрирует подход "лишь бы сделать": так как сложность кода совершенно неадекватна сложности задачи. В реальной работе, такой индусский код недопустим - за подобное могут даже уволить, на полном серьезе. Вместо того чтобы огрызаться на конструктивное замечание, ознакомься с документацией метода `setMonth()` и принципами эффективного программирования. Это поможет тебе и данную проблему решить, и не совершать таких же ошибок в будущем.

Comment: Процитирую с MDN: «If a parameter you specify is outside of the expected range, setMonth() attempts to update the date information in the Date object accordingly. For example, if you use 15 for monthValue, the year will be incremented by 1, and 3 will be used for month.»

Comment: @yar85 Я вас понял, просто эти задачи я делаю для себя, точнее для понимания тех или иных методов,  если еще точнее чтобы не писать повторяющий код. Спасибо за setMonth() оно как раз нужно))

Comment: @КамранРаджабов, и data-атрибуты тоже нужны (с ними проще написать обработчик). Пример: https://jsbin.com/wuvuyuxeze/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @yar85 я уже сам понял)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function organizer() {

  var date = new Date();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = date.getMonth();

  forward.addEventListener("click", function() {
    month = forwardClick(month, year);
  });
}

function forwardClick(monthElem, yearElem) {

  var newDate = new Date(yearElem, monthElem += 1);
  if (newDate.getMonth() == 11) {
    newDate.setFullYear(newDate.getFullYear() + 1);
  }

  alert(newDate);
  return monthElem;
}

organizer();
```

```html
<button id="forward">&#9658;</button>
```

Comment: нужно  чтобы выводила всю дату

Comment: разобрался, вечером просто голова не работала не понял что написал, спасибо за помощь